# Promise and handling of errors in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling, promise, es6-promise

I am testing to rewrite som `XMLHttpRequest`-code with HTML5 `Promise`.

I did a mistake and the code in `thePromise.then(failingCode)` failed. This give a call to the `reject` function used when setting up the `Promise`.

I had to search a while to catch the error since I did not get any Call stack and no line number where the error occured.

That is of course very inconvenient.

How should I handle this? Should I send a bug report to the Google Chrome developers? Or, is it my own fault?

Comment: To be fair help is on its way: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1722#issuecomment-70754912

Comment: That looks nice, @BenjaminGruenbaum! Though it actually does not help to find the exact location of the problem. You can combine it with me answer here below. That gives some extra information. (So it looks like I should file another bug report for Chrome.)

Comment: There _is_ a way to get the call stack in Google Chrome - that way is async stack traces and you can see it in the link I posted above. If you want to always have it don't use native promises use Bluebird which stitches stack traces and has much better traces.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. This question should be tagged as google-chrome.

Comment: Thanks @jib, I was not aware of the tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just realized that there is a way to get the call stack in Google Chrome. Though it is a bit inconvenient you can do like this:

```
function failingCode(arg) {
    try {
        ... the failing code ...
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("failingCode error: "+e.stack);
        debugger;
    }
}
```

Please notice that if you throw an error you need to use the `Error` function to get a stack. (Simply `throw "my message"` will not give a stack.)

**UPDATE**
Reported as a Chrome bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=458306

Comment: I think you'll want to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/28427407/1048572. There is good debug tooling coming for promises.